# edb-as11-server-11.10.19-1-windows-x64 - pgadmin 4 -v4 (11) stopped working after installed and uninstall postgresql-13.13-1-windows-x64

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, pgadmin-4, edb

edb-as11-server-11.10.19-1-windows-x64 - pgadmin 4 -v4 (11) - installed long back in my laptop (windows 10) and due to project demand I installed postgresql-13.13-1-windows-x64 but facing some issue during installation so uninstalled postgresql-13.13-1-windows-x64, then when I try to use edb-as11-server-11.10.19-1-windows-x64 - **pgadmin 4 -v4 (11)** its stopped working,  pgadmin popup opens and its says **Staring pgAdmin4 server...** and immediately the popup closed without showing any errors.

Comment: That question contains zero information. pgAdmin is fickle. Try using a different client.